# How can I set the command override on an ECS scheduled task via Terraform?

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using this module - https://registry.terraform.io/modules/cn-terraform/ecs-fargate-scheduled-task/aws/latest

I've managed to build the scheduled task with everything except the command override on the container

I cannot set the command override at the task definition level because multiple scheduled tasks implement the same task definition so the command override needs to happen at the scheduled task level as it's unique per scheduled task

I don't see anything that helps in the modules documentation so i'm wondering if there is another way I could do this by either querying for the scheduled task once it's created and using a different module to set the command override?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_target) for `aws_cloudwatch_event_target`, there is an example in there for an ECS scheduled task with command override. Notice how they are passing the override via the `input` parameter to the event target.

Now if you look at [the source code](https://github.com/cn-terraform/terraform-aws-ecs-fargate-scheduled-task/blob/main/main.tf) for the module you are using, you will see they are passing anything you set in the `event_target_input` variable to the `input` parameter of the `aws_cloudwatch_event_target` resource.

So you need to pass the override as a JSON string (I would copy the example JSON string in the Terraform docs and then modify it to your needs) as `event_target_input` in your module declaration.

Comment: That sounds very confident and promising. Thank you for the help!

Comment: That has worked. Thank you again for your help. It's very much appreciated!